# Is it efficient way to get all the page data on the base of URL String

Tags: php, performance, url, web

I have seen so many websites where when open any page there is no any numeric Id or some thing like this in the URL, Just the URL String with hyphens(-) in between the words. It means that the Page is retrieving the data on the basis of string from the database. And some URLs are very long. It means there could be no any Index on that field in the database (as it is so long). So, Is it an efficient way, If not, Why so many sites, use this method?

Answer (score 2):

Some sites, like this one (stackoverflow) uses a hybrid approach, having both a numeric index **AND** a string canonical title for the url. Like the url of this same page:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/15221783/is-it-efficient-way-to-get-all-the-page-data-on-the-base-of-url-string
//          Numeric index -----^                ^-------- canonical title
```

This way you have the best of both worlds, a fast numeric index, and the semantic seo-friendly canonical string title.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite efficient, as you can index only, say, first 15 characters of the string. 
However, this approach is wrong in general, because unique page should be addressed by unique url, while page title can be edited.

If you edit your question title, the old url will bring you back on the right page.
In case of the system you described, there is no way to get back if title was edited.
So, a good site will never use it, but, like stackoerflow, will use both unique index and a slug.

Answer (score -1):

Its not inefficient, as the routing system of the framework takes the work out of most of the searching. For example, `products/en-gb/mens/shirts/light-blue-full-sleeve-twill-shirt` can be broken down into the products category, followed by en-gb, followed by mens and shirts, those categories would be linked to each other and the product is linked to the shirts category, so you are not searching the whole database, but a subset of it in any case.

And unless you have millions of pages and categories on the site, databases can quite easily search a few thousand records before you can blink.